# Wiremock Webhook callback Spring boot integration test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, wiremock

We have an asynchronous application meaning we send a request to an API that accepts the request immediately and returns 200. The server then processes the request and calls back an API with the results of the above processing. Example :

1. Make a call to `Server A` on `POST /order`
2. `Server A` calls `POST /processor/order` on `Server B` which creates an Order.
3. `Server B` processes the Order
4. `Server B` calls back URL `POST /order/callback/{1}` on `Server A`
5. `Server A` processes the response

I tried to write an integration test for this using `Spring Boot Tests` and `WireMock Webhooks` which looks something like this :

```
@Test
void shouldReturnCallbackAndProcessOrder() {
    // test setup ...
    
    wm.stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/processor/order"))
    .willReturn(ok())
    .withPostServeAction("webhook", webhook()
        .withMethod(POST)
        .withUrl("http://my-target-host/order/callback/1")
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .withBody("{ \"result\": \"SUCCESS\" }"))
    );

 ...some assertions here...
 Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I need to put this line `Thread.sleep(1000);` at the end of the test to wait for the webhook to call the `Server A`. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/), which allows you to wrap a checking operation inside a lambda and it will be repeatedly checked until it's passed or a timeout is reached e.g.

```java
await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until(/* fetch some value */, is("expected value"));
```

WireMock uses this for its own async testing: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/25b82f9f97f3cc09136097b249cfd37aef924c36/src/test/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/PostServeActionExtensionTest.java#L85